# MVC 3 - Render additional Editor templates for children objects

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a form that allows the user to create an an entity with 0-multiple children objects, the main object being a `Lead` which has 0-many `Beneficiary` and `Payer` objects. The relation between the three is as follows:

```
Lead has many Beneficiaries (one to many)
Lead has many Payers (many to many) joined through LeadsPayers
```

In my editor for my lead view model I have a loop that generates the editor for each beneficiary and payer attached to the lead but I want to be able to have a button that will dynamically add another beneficiary or payer to the lead and use the editor template so i don't have duplicated html in my javascript code.

I have this working to bind everything to the `Lead` when my form gets posted to the controller I just don't know how to reuse the editor template code to generate compatible html with my current form, has anyone done this before? There has to be a better way than an ajax button that renders the html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This helped me get on the right track](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) but wasn't fully what I wanted to do and as this doesn't seem easily supported in MVC here is my work around to get this all to work with model binding in the controller.

#### My end goal

To dynamically add children objects to a form with the proper html so that they would be auto bound to the parent when passed to the control method, meaning I needed HTML like this

```
<input name='Lead_Beneficiaries_1__{Property}' id=... />
```

And not like this (which is what the blog post results in)

```
<input name='Beneficiary__{Property}' />
```

Which doesn't auto bind to the parent when posted to the controller.

#### Solution

Instead of using Ajax to render the editor template html from the controller, I auto render one editor template when the form is loaded and then more can be loaded as needed by the user. JQuery code

```
$("#addBeneficiary").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var beneficiary = $(".beneficiary:last").clone();
    var count = parseInt(beneficiary.find("input:first").attr("id").match(/\d+/), 10);
    beneficiary.find("input").each(function(indx, element) { 
        var name = $(element).attr('name').replace(count, count+1),
            id   = $(element).attr('id').replace(count, count+1);
        $(element).attr('name', name);
        $(element).attr('id', id);
        $(element).val(''); 
    });
    $("#beneficiaries").append(beneficiary);
});
```

I just wrapped my editor template in a div so it can be easily grabbed as a whole from jquery, cloned it, emptied the values of the inputs and incremented the counter for each element so when posted I get a collection of children entities on my parent without having to explicitly catch them in the method or pull them from the formcollection dictionary.

While this probably isn't the best solution, it gets the job done in the way I intended and I didn't end up duplicating HTML for the editor template. Also if the form errors since the parent object has the multiple children they get auto rendered automatically by my form code and nothing is lost because of client side additions.

Comment: amazing man! i m impressed. there is only one thing i m concerned about this solution how would we handle the situation if someone deletes a row from the middle

Comment: you'd need some javascript to update the counters for each set of fields

Comment: @Jimmy +1 most excellent. I needed to do more or less the same and this works perfect. One tweak I made was that I have a couple of hidden fields that need to have value 0, so I just check the input type and set val to 0 if it's a hidden field:                    "if ($(element).attr('type') === 'hidden')"

Answer (score 2):

For a variable length list with jquery you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

In your main view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... some other input fields on the main view model       

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Beneficiaries)

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and inside the editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/Beneficiary.cshtml`):

```
@model AppName.Models.Beneficiary
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.BeneficiaryName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BeneficiaryName)
</div>
....
```

The naming convention is important: the editor template should be called XXX.cshtml and located in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder where XXX is the type of the collection:

```
public IEnumerable<XXX> Beneficiaries { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is what I have currently, all working fine, but I want to dynamically add new children entities on the client side, great tip on using the collection as the editorfor target instead of a loop!

Comment: @Jimmy, did you checkout the Steve Sanderson's [blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) I've linked to?

Comment: Reading it now and it looks like exactly what I want, will update when I get something working. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem I'm running into is this doesn't tie the new objects to the parent and all of the dynamically added objects have the same field names

Comment: While the blog post helped a lot, it still doesn't answer the question of dynamically adding `children` to a parent model object, when I add them with the method described they don't have the nested html names that would associate it with my model object when posted to a control and even the forms collection gets entries overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

This question is super old but I have another technique for solving it.

I create a script template, ie:

```
<script type="text/html" id="deliveryTemplate">
    @{ 
        var Deliveries = new List<ChristmasOrderDeliveryForm> { new ChristmasOrderDeliveryForm() };
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deliveries )
    }
</script>
```

I use this to create a new section and with javascript similar to @pistol-pete

The reason I use a template instead of cloning an existing row is so that all data is set to defaults, etc

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to do this myself, and came up with a very similar solution before finding this question. My solution seems *cleaner* (to me) and handles not only `<input>` tags but also `<label>` and `<select>` tags and any other form elements. I adapted my code to match the original question.

Html Sample:

```
<ul id="beneficiaries">
    <li class="beneficiary">
        <p>
            <label for="Lead_Beneficiaries_0__FirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="Lead_Beneficiaries_0__FirstName" name="Lead.Beneficiaries[0].FirstName" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Lead_Beneficiaries_0__LastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="Lead_Beneficiaries_0__LastName" name="Lead.Beneficiaries[0].LastName" />
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>

<button type="button" id="addBeneficiary">Add Beneficiary</button>
```

JavaScript to add a new Editor Template item:

```
$('#addBeneficiary').click(function () {

    var count = $('.beneficiary').length;
    var clone = $('.beneficiary:first').clone();

    clone.html(function (index, html) {
        return html
            .replace(/Beneficiaries\[0\]/g, 'Beneficiaries[' + count + ']')
            .replace(/Beneficiaries_0__/g, 'Beneficiaries_' + count + '__');
    });

    $('.beneficiary:last').after(clone);
});
```