# jQuery UI Datepicker on copied html elements with datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form in which a user can add a set of fields dynamically as needed. The code for that just copies the last entry and increments the counters in the field names (work around for my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093677/mvc-3-render-additional-editor-templates-for-children-objects)) The code follows:

```
$("#addBeneficiary").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var beneficiary = $(".beneficiary:last").clone();
    var count = parseInt(beneficiary.find("input:first").attr("id").match(/\d+/), 10);
    beneficiary.find("input").each(function(indx, element) { 
        var name = $(element).attr('name').replace(count, count+1),
            id   = $(element).attr('id').replace(count, count+1);
        $(element).attr('name', name);
        $(element).attr('id', id);
        $(element).val(''); 
    });

    $("#beneficiaries").append(beneficiary);
    datepicker();
});
```

The last line `datepicker();` is just a function that finds all `input.datepicker` and executes the jQuery UI `datepicker()` function to add date pickers to those fields. The problem I'm running into is this; the datepicker works fine on the first fields, but when they are dynamically added the datepicker doesn't pop up for the new fields.

I've traced the code execution with logging statements to ensure my `datepicker()` function is called after the append and that all works. Here is my `datepicker()` code

```
var datepicker = function() {
    $("input.datepicker").datepicker();
};
```

Does anyone know why this is not working as expected?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Why not just `.datepicker()` the newly created input?

Comment: No errors and tried that as well, no such luck, focus doesn't produce a datepicker

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it has to do with the clone. I know you can accomplish this with a live datepicker activation for they dynamically added elements. Try out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVBsj/1/).

```
$("input.datepicker").live('focus', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.data('datepicker')) $this.datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, this works only if the user hasn't focused on the first element that is to be copied before adding more, even changing it to just call datepicker on focus doesn't work

Comment: @Jimmy - I can't reproduce what you are talking about. You will no longer need to call datepicker each time a row is added. It only needs to be called `onready` because it is a live event. Did you try out the example?

Comment: I did, was just trying new methods to see if i could get anything working